# Значительное увеличение размера спрайтов при добавлении в unity

Tags: unity3d

При добавлении изображения .png формата в unity весом примерно в 9 Кб это же изображение в unity весит 1 Мб. Объясните, почему так.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: каковы ваши доказательства? есть скрины или еще что-то?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Добавил скрин

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы чуть-чуть спутали. *Unity* ничего не увеличивает.

То, что в свойствах картинки — **физический** размер на диске. А то, что отображается в *Unity* (внизу справа) — это размер картинки **в памяти**.

В вашем случае получается следующее:

```
501 x 501 x 4 bytes (32 bits) = 251 001 x 4 bytes = 1 004 004 bytes = ~0.957 MB = ~1.0MB
```

С размером — всё.

Если вы хотите оптимизировать потребление и уменьшить размер текстуры в памяти, то можно поиграть с настройками, например *Format* или *MaxSize* или даже в настройках `TextureType` выбрать `Advanced` и там настраивать.

---

**P.S.** Постарайтесь не делать изображений, стороны которых имеют нечетное значение. Стороны **должны быть** кратны 2, например *100x200* или *256x512*, а вообще рекомендация, особенно относительно мобильных платформ — вписывать картинки в текстуру кратной **степени** двойки (Power of 2), например  *256x256* или *512x512* и т.д. Ссылка: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html, пункт "Размеры текстур"

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. А что не так с нечетными размерами, почему нельзя?

Comment: @Shadr это обширная тема и много можно чего сказать. Если цитировать то "NPOT (не кратное двойке) обычно использует немного больше памяти может медленнее читаться графическим процессором,  для производительности лучше использовать размеры степеней двойки везде, где только можно. Если платформа или графический процессор не поддерживает текстуры NPOT размера, то тогда Unity изменит их размеры до ближайших, равных степени двойки, что потребует ещё больше памяти и сделает загрузку медленнее"..........также невозможно применить некоторые виды компрессии к ним......

Comment: @Shadr а с неквадратными текстурами (даже если делятся на 2, но не является степенью двойки) вообще могут быть проблемы на мобильных платформах..там вообще желательно делать их как **POT**.... далее... в квадратном атласе **могут** быть спрайты с нечетными размерами, однако это может сказаться например при построении сцены где спрайты могут просто несостыковаться друг с другом и иметь разрывы... В GUI вроде можно делать, но в целом - не стоит